# Php Concat variable to link tag

Tags: php, laravel

I need to concat a variable to a link tag. But I fail. Any tips or ideas?

```
$styleLocation = mix('css/app.css');

$style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href=$styleLocation>';
```

Currently it returns:

> "<link rel="stylesheet" href=echo $styleLocation>"

Comment: If this is in a blade file, then simply do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">`

Comment: `$style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $styleLocation . '">';` Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the string like this:

```
$style = "<link rel='stylesheet' href=$styleLocation>";
```

You can write variable names inside double quotes